# Parse specific data in an XML file

Tags: xml, xmllint

So this is the full XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ldap_users><size>1</size><ldap_user><uid>1396255</uid><uuid/><username>JSmith</username><realname>John Smith</realname><real_name>John Smith</real_name><email_address>jsmith@cookecenter.org</email_address><phone/><phone_number/><building/><department/><room/><position/></ldap_user></ldap_users>
```

I am trying to only get the information for the "real_name" output into terminal when I run my script. Currently I have the script downloading the XML locally and then running **xmllint** like this:

```
sudo -u root xmllint --xpath 'string(//@real_name)' /Library/Application\ Support/JAMF/user.xml
```

But I am not getting anything in terminal. Can someone show me the right way if this is possible? If I am doing something wrong, what is the right way?

Comment: I think you meant, //real_name .  @ operator is for an attribute.

Comment: And maybe add the /text() behind the //real_name to only show the content. you can test your xpath query using online tooling on websites als freeformatter.com. This can be a big help in finding errors.